# How to make a diff using nbdiff-web of a Jupyter notebook stored on git?

Tags: python, git, jupyter

Is there a simple way to make a diff of the latest version of the Jupyter notebook with its previous version using the nbdime tool's nbdiff-web command.

http://nbdime.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli.html#nbdiff-web

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely you can use [this extension](https://github.com/jupyter/nbdime/blob/master/docs/source/vcs.rst) to achieve the same with ease.

It has version control integration with git.